# Swt StyledText lose caret while adapte it into swt Tree component

Tags: eclipse, treeview, swt, editor, jface

My purpose is to add a styled text for Tree composite in SWT application.
No problem I can add it and use, but caret of styledText is missing.

After investigation, it should be reason of Tree / Table. both missing.
But it works on Canvas.

```java
display = new Display();
shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

final Composite baseComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
baseComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
baseComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

final Tree tree = new Tree(baseComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

StyledText styledText = new StyledText(tree, SWT.BORDER );
```

Is this the platform limitation or the conflict between Tree and StyledText?

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for `Tree` says:

> Note that although this class is a subclass of Composite, it does not
>   normally make sense to add Control children to it, or set a layout on
>   it, unless implementing something like a cell editor.

So adding `StyledText` as a direct child is not really supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes that I adopted way is cell editor. In a Tree, I used TreeEditor -> CellEditor -> CompositeContainer -> StyledText for display the rich format text. Everything looks fine except this annoying issue of Caret. By debugging, the caret is initialized and works but invisible. really wired. BTW, works normal in Canvas.

Comment: I assume Tree is not working well with StyledText on Caret display. I think StyledText overwritten the "handle", but StyledText Caret drawing rely on "handle". It should be one compatibility bug.